# Answer not being posted and captcha error

Tags: bug, answers, captcha

I've been trying to submit an answer for the question: [Can't assign Value to php date Box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23181934/cant-assign-value-to-php-date-box)

However, the answer is not submitting. When I try to browse the page as an anonymous user from another browser, the answer shows.

I tried re-submitting it again, and captcha comes up, but then I get "An error occurred while submitting the captcha" error. I've tried it several times and I'm pretty sure I submitted a correct captcha.

Any Ideas why this happened?

**Note:** I'm trying with both Firefox and Chrome

**Update:** If I try submitting the captcha twice, they give me "incorrect word" error and then reloads the captcha.

**Update 2:** My answer finally got posted. I'm not sure what happened now. Captcha screen didn't even come up. I just made a comment with the answer, then posted the answer and it worked.. Any explanations?

Comment: Blacklisted or shared IP maybe? Just a suggestion to check...